# User icon path narrows unexpectedly when exporting SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

I have a user icon I'm trying to export to SVG. The arc of the body narrows when exporting to SVG but appears fine when in Illustrator.  Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Illustrator v24.0

[person.svg](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/27444/person.svg)

[person.ai](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/27444/person.ai)

**As displayed in Illustrator**
[image: User icon as displayed in Illustrator]

**As displayed in Illustrator (outlines)**
[image]

**Exported SVG**
[image]

Comment: Could you share the SVG code please?

Comment: Please add the version of Illustrator you are using to the question.

Comment: I've added links to the exported SVG and original Illustrator files in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounding errors I suppose. In your SVG export dialogue, did you set *Decimal Places* to `0` or `1`? Add a higher value for decimal places, default should be `3`. For such a tiny drawing (32x32px) I'd recommend even more (like 6).